# The simultaneous gossip problem

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, soft-question

In the simultaneous gossip problem we have $n>1$ spies. Each of them has a unique piece of information.
In a number of rounds, pairs of spies are formed and each pair exchanges the information they have.
If, after a number of rounds, every spy has all information, we have found a solution.
Let $r(n)$ be the smallest value $k$ such that a solution in $k$ rounds is possible.

Alon Amit gave a gentle treatment of the case $n=5$ in https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-the-Waterloo-problem-of-the-week-The-Spys-The-Limit.
In one of the comments he wrote "I doubt the general solution for n spies is nice.".
The theorem below shows that this feeling is incorrect: the general solution actually *is* nice.

Theorem: $r(n)=\left\lceil{\log_2 n}\right\rceil$ if $n$ is even and $r(n)=\left\lceil{\log_2 n}\right\rceil+1$ if $n$ is odd.

Searching the internet, I did find a statement that bounds for $r(n)$ were published, but nowhere a reference to a full solution. Does anyone know if this problem has been completely solved and, if yes, can you provide a reference?

For those interested, here is a proof.

In every round the number of spies that know a given piece of information is at most doubled. This implies that $r(n)\geq\left\lceil{\log_2 n}\right\rceil$ for all $n$.

If $n$ is a power of $2$, say $n=2^k$, there is an easy and well-known solution: we locate the spies at the vertices of the hypercube $Q_k$.
The edges in this hypercube have $k$ different directions.
In round $i$ we pair all spies that are at the endpoints of some edge in direction $i$.
This gives us a solution in $k$ rounds, proving the claim for this specific case. We will call this the hypercube solution.

If $n$ is odd, at least one spy is not paired at all in the first round. This means that at least
$\left\lceil{\log_2 n}\right\rceil$ *additional* rounds are needed to propulse his information to everyone, hence $r(n)\geq\left\lceil{\log_2 n}\right\rceil+1$.

We can uniquely write $n=2^k+s$ for positive integers $k$ and $s$ with $0<s<2^k$.
A solution in $\left\lceil{\log_2 n}\right\rceil+1=k+2$ rounds is created as follows.
In the first round each of the last $s$ spies is paired with one of the first $2^k$ spies, so after this round the first $2^k$ spies together have all information. Then we use $k$ rounds implementing the hypercube solution for the first $2^k$ spies, so each of them knows everything after $k+1$ rounds. The last round duplicates the pairing in the first round. This solution in $k+2$ rounds proves the claim for odd $n$.

It remains to show that for even $n$ a solution in $r=\left\lceil{\log_2 n}\right\rceil$ rounds can be found.
We imagine the $n$ spies $p_0,\ldots,p_{n-1}$ standing in a circle, evenly spaced.
We define the pairing in each of $r$ rounds.
For a positive integer $j$ let $d(j)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{j-1}(-2)^k$. Note that $d(j)$ is odd for all $j$. The sequence $(d(j))$ starts with $1,-1,3,-5,11,\ldots$.

In round $j$ spy $p_i$ is paired to spy $p_{i+d(j)}$ for every even $i$, where indices are taken $\pmod n$. We label the corresponding edges with $j$. Since every $d(j)$ is odd, this defines a complete pairing for every round.

The configuration of edges has both rotational symmetry (using a rotation angle of $\frac{4\pi}n$) and mirror-symmetry, so in order to prove that after $k$ rounds every person has obtained all information, it is sufficient to show that every person receives the information initially known to $p_0$. This is equivalent to the requirement that there is an increasing edge path from $p_0$ to every $p_i$.
This means that the possible sums $\sum\limits_{i=1}^s(-1)^{i-1}d(t_i)$, taken over all increasing sublists $1\leq t_1<t_2<\ldots<t_s\leq k$ must take all possible values $\pmod n$. (Because all $d(i)$ are odd, an increasing path alternates between spies with even index and spies with odd index, and for spies with odd index the chord goes in opposite direction, which explains the factor $(-1)^{i-1}$.)
We investigate the possible sums.

If $s$ is even, we pair the summands to get a sum of contributions of the form $d(t_i)-d(t_{i+1})$ with $i$ odd, which equals $-\sum\limits_{k=t_i}^{t_{i+1}-1}(-2)^k$. Note that this is always an even number.
Because we run over all possible increasing sublists, this gives us exactly all sums of type $-\sum\limits_{A\subseteq[r-1],i\in A}(-2)^i$.
Similarly, if $s$ is odd we get all sums of type $1+\sum\limits_{A\subseteq[r-1],i\in A}(-2)^i$.
It is trivially shown (by induction on $r$) that the values of type $-\sum\limits_{A\subseteq[r-1],i\in A}(-2)^i$ consist of $2^{r-1}$ consecutive even integers. The values of type $1+\sum\limits_{A\subseteq[r-1],i\in A}(-2)^i$ consist of $2^{r-1}$ consecutive odd integers.

It remains to show that this covers all values $\pmod n$, for $n\leq2^r$.

This is obvious when $n$ is even, but unfortunately I found no elegant way to show it for odd $n$, so the last part elaborates on the actual ranges of the value. I would be grateful if someone found a more elegant solution.

For odd $r$, the even numbers range from $-\frac43(2^{r-1}-1)$ to $\frac23(2^{r-1}-1)$ (*) and for even $r$ the even numbers range from $-\frac43(2^{r-2}-1)$ to $\frac23(2^r-1)$.

For odd $r$, the odd numbers range from $-\frac23(2^{r-1}-1)+1$ to $\frac43(2^{r-1}-1)+1$ (**) and for even $r$ the odd numbers range from $-\frac23(2^r-1)+1$ to $\frac43(2^{r-2}-1)+1$.

Assume $n$ odd, so $0<n<2^r$, and $0\leq k<n$. To see that $k$ is covered $\pmod n$, we just treat one case, say $r$ is odd and $k$ is odd.

If $k\leq\frac43(2^{r-1}-1)+1$ we are done because of rule (**).
Otherwise we have $k-n\geq k-2^r+1>\frac43(2^{r-1}-1)+1-2^r+1=-\frac13(2^r-1)$
and because $k-n$ is an even, negative number, and $-\frac13(2^r-1)\geq-\frac43(2^{r-1}-1)$, $k-n$ is covered  by rule (*), and hence $k$ is covered $\pmod n$.

The other three cases are similar.

REMARK: when $n$ is a power of $2$, we have given two different constructions for a solution. It turns out, that for $n=4$ the constructions are essentially identical, for $n=8$ the constructions are different, but the underlying graphs are isomorphic, and for higher values of $n$ not even the underlying graphs are isomorphic.